# Silex : log dbal exceptions

Tags: exception, logging, console, silex, dbal

I'm using Silex micro-framework. I searched a method to log every dbal exceptions (from requests, console commands, etc...)

I didn't find something which works. Even if I declare a callback function in `$app->error();`, it doesn't works to Console exceptions

How can I tell to dbal to log in a file all db errors/exceptions ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the fat version of Silex you should already have exception logging with [MonologServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/monolog.html), as long as it has been registered.

The console is usually an instance of [Symfony\Component\Console\Application](https://github.com/symfony/Console/blob/master/Application.php) (not [Silex\Application](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Application.php)).

**Edit** One way to accomplish logging console exceptions is to set console catch exceptions to false:

```
$console->setCatchExceptions(false);
```

And then wrap `$console->run();` in a try catch:

```
try {
    $console->run();
}
catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {
    $app['monolog']->addError(sprintf('Console DBALException %s %s %s', $e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine()));
}
catch(\Exception $e) {
    $app['monolog']->addError(sprintf('Console Exception %s %s %s', $e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine()));
}
```